# Is $E=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | y^2-xy-x^3=0\}$ compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

> Tell if the subset $E=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | y^2-xy-x^3=0\}$ of $(\mathbb R^2,\epsilon_1)$, with $\epsilon_1 $the usual topology is compact.

The solution I was given:

> For each $n \in \mathbb N$, the equation $-x^3-nx+n^2=0$ has at least one real root $x_n$. Then, the unbounded sequence $(x_n,n)$ is  contained in E, from which E is not compact.

I really don't understand it. Can someone please explain

1) why the equation has at least one real root, is it Descartes' rule?

2) how do we know the sequence is unbounded, could they all be contain in a bounded region like inside a circle or something, how to tell?

Comment: Sorry I forgot the equation, i just added it

Comment: One real root is a consequence of intermediate value theorem. If x is positive enough, the function is positive. Likewise for negative. Therefore the function must be zero somewhere in between by continuity.

Comment: $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}, (x,y) \mapsto y^2 -xy-x^3$ is continuous. So $E=f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is a closed set. Since closed + bounded implies compact in finite vector spaces, you kind of need to show that it is unbounded. That is why you look for a sequence which is unbounded. And $(x_n,n)\in E$ is unbounded since n goes to infinity.

Comment: The sequence is unbounded bc it's unbounded on the y axis. Therefore no circle can contain it.

Comment: when would this approach work for other functions?

Comment: Juan.Cubic equation has at least one real root. X to + infinity , x^3+...goes to infinity, x to -infinity x^3+...goes to - infinity. Continuous function, a zero in between. n can be any pos integer , 1000,1000, you name it , bounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you fix $y$, you have a cubic in $x$. Then a real root exists, because the function $f(x)=-x^3-xy+y^2$ is continuous and has $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=+\infty$, while $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=-\infty$.  Or you can argue that complex roots appear in pairs when the coefficients are real.

In any case, now you can take $y=n$, and you get a root $x_n$. That is, $n^2-nx_n-x_n^3=0$. So you get points in your set of the form $(x_n,n)$. The distance to the origin is $\sqrt{x_n^2+n^2}\geq n$, so the sequence is unbounded.

Comment: when would this approach work for other functions?

Comment: That's too vague of a question, I guess. What's used in this case is that $f$ is continuous, and that it takes both positive an negative values for any choice of $y$.